# HOW TO INSERT rows into table 1 with column values from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

**table1**

```
contactid, LabId, date, createdby
```

table 2:

```
contactid
12
13
14
15
16
```

**table3** 
   Labid
    4567

I would like to write sql query which inserts the data from table 2 and table 3 into Table1.

output should be like:

**table1**

```
contactid, LabId,  date,     createdby
12         4567   10/26/2018    Vish
13         4567   10/26/2018    Vish
14         4567   10/26/2018    Vish
15         4567   10/26/2018    Vish
16         4567   10/26/2018    Vish
```

**Note:**  contactid and Labid are together Primary Key non-clustered.
I have scenario I would like to insert into table1 only if Contactid and Labid values do not exists in table1. can any one help me with this please.

I tried below code but its not working.

If Not Exists(select * from table1 where labid in (select labid from table3 ) and contactid in (select contactid from table2))
Begin
Insert into table1 (contactid, LabId, date, createdby)
SELECT contactid,(select * from table3),getdate(),'Vish' 
FROM table2

Please help.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the table structure? It will be helpful to answer. And also does `table3` contain `contactid` column?

Comment: nope. Table_3 do not contain contactid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, since there is only one value in `table3`

```
insert into table1 (contactid, LabId, date, createdby)
SELECT contactid,4567,'10/26/2018','Vish' 
FROM table2
```

Or if the value changes

```
Insert into table1 (contactid, LabId, date, createdby)
SELECT contactid,(select * from table3),getdate(),'Vish' 
FROM table2
```

Comment: I would like to put this query in stored proc and has to be run every day. Most importantly the value in Table 3 "4567"  changes every day.

Comment: Could you please vote my post. So that it increases my reputation as well.

Comment: @Vadiya I actually did upvote your post a long time ago, but asking for votes is frowned upon I would think. The reason it is at 0 is because someone also downvoted you. You can see how many upvotes and downvotes you have by clicking the number

Comment: Note: contactid and Labid are together Primary Key non-clustered. I have scenario I would like to insert into table1 only if Contactid and Labid values do not exists in table1. can any one help me with this please.

I tried below code but its not working.

If Not Exists(select * from table1 where labid in (select labid from table3 ) and contactid in (select contactid from table2)) Begin Insert into table1 (contactid, LabId, date, createdby) SELECT contactid,(select * from table3),getdate(),'Vish' FROM table2

Please help.Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to ask a new question for this. Only I see this comment because I get an alert. No one else.